# How to perform a pairwise correlation in a Pandas dataframe containing lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a Pandas dataframe, called `df2`, which looks as follows when I print it:

```
                                                      728
100610  [0.8872128569054152, 0.6275935748500376, 0.105...
102311  [-0.9484644612008593, -1.7934280570087853, -2....
104416  [0.1664251633793124, 0.1116268791242702, 0.050...
105923  [-0.2307886056759264, -0.5762187864896702, -0....
```

The column on the very left (`100610 102311 104416 105923`) are four subjects from which the data stems. Every subject has a time-series of 150 sampling points. For example, subject `100610` has the time-series `[0.8872128569054152, 0.6275935748500376, 0.105...` and so on.

I am running a sliding window pairwise correlation approach (728 sliding windows). The number `728` denotes the last sliding window in a for loop. The output above is a paradigmatic example of the very last sliding window of `df2`.

**Aim:** I would like to run a pairwise correlation between the four subjects (between the subjects’ time-series) as follows:

```
pairwise_cor = df2.corr(method="pearson")
```

However, this results in the following and empty output for `pairwise_cor`:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

**Question:**
How do I have to modify the code for `pairwise_cor = df2.corr(method="pearson")` so that the code does not produce an empty output?

As far as my understanding goes, the problem is based on the fact that every row contains a list or array of values. `pairwise_cor = df2.corr(method="pearson")` would probably work if I could transpose the dataframe so that every column corresponds to one subject, and every row to one value of the list. Is that correct? How could I modify the dataframe so change it accordingly?

Comment: please provide a reproducible object as input, using a DataFrame constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[0.07717473, 0.90724758, 0.80752715, 0.04318562, 0.0569035, 0.12796062, 0.220677, 0.3716013, 0.74646015, -0.41114205],
        [-0.12252081, 0.03894384, -0.74668061, 0.00310963, 0.10716717, -0.42125924, 0.90771138, 0.10498123, 0.60872, -0.62587628],
        [-0.24917124, -0.76921359, 0.55519856, 0.56067116, -0.27319101, -0.01258496, 0.66428267, 0.53822299, -0.86883193, -0.15486245],
        [-0.14676444, 0.21910793, -0.11010598, 0.86445147, -0.92299316, -0.82828022, -0.7274392, 0.66965337, 0.67446502, -0.50343198]]
df = pd.Series(data, index=[100610, 102311, 104416, 105923]).to_frame(728)
print(df)

# Output
                                                      728
100610  [0.07717473, 0.90724758, 0.80752715, 0.0431856...
102311  [-0.12252081, 0.03894384, -0.74668061, 0.00310...
104416  [-0.24917124, -0.76921359, 0.55519856, 0.56067...
105923  [-0.14676444, 0.21910793, -0.11010598, 0.86445...
```

You can use [`np.corrcoef`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) to deal with vectors:

```
>>> np.corrcoef(np.vstack(df.loc[:, 728]))

array([[ 1.        ,  0.19332151, -0.23634425,  0.40882581],
       [ 0.19332151,  1.        , -0.08039743,  0.15825333],
       [-0.23634425, -0.08039743,  1.        , -0.02293406],
       [ 0.40882581,  0.15825333, -0.02293406,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. Two questions. (1): via ```df.loc[:, 728])``` you select all rows of the column ```728```, (2) and via ```np.vstack``` you nest each row as a list into one numpy array. Finally, ```np.corrcoef``` allows a pairwise correlation of the numpy array (that includes nested lists). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are right for both.